# Producing a Nonetype error - Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, generator

When moving from the `get_page_data` function to `for` loop to extract business name, address etc. there's a problem which is giving a `Nonetype` error.  I now know that means that a value of `None` is being passed into the `for` loop, but I'm not sure what's causing this error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#Read csv
with open ("gyms4.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    csvfilelist = [row[0] for row in reader]

#Get data from each url
def get_page_data():
    for page_data in csvfilelist:
        r = requests.get(page_data.strip())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        yield soup

#Complete work on data
for page in get_page_data():
        name = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_TITLE"}).text
        address = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_map_location"}).text
        phoneNum = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_phoneNum"}).text
        email = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_EMAIL"}).text

        th = pages.find('b',text="Category")
        td = th.findNext()
        for link in td.findAll('a',href=True):
            match = re.search(r'http://(\w+).(\w+).(\w+)', link.text)
            if match:
                web_address = link.text

gyms = [name,address,phoneNum,email,web_address]
gyms.append(gyms)

#Saving specific listing data to csv
with open ("xgyms.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in gyms:
        writer.writerow([row])
```

Comment: One of your expressions returned a value of "None", which has no field "text" (or any other field).  The full error message should give you a line number.

Comment: Now you get to trace which one failed, and where -- usually with a temporary variable, such as /// temp = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_TITLE"}) /// print temp /// name = temp.text ///

Comment: The line that extracts titles:  `name = page.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_TITLE"}).text`

Comment: before you ask for the text attribute, do a check on your object to ensure its what you expect. im guessing that request.get(...) is return none, ie there's nothing to get

Comment: @McLeodx, so it's possible that _all_ of them will fail.  Use that temp variable to start tracking the problem.

Comment: I've tried printing `r` and it shows the error `Nameerror: Name r is not defined`, when I print `get_page_data` it shows: `<generator object get_page_data at 0x10437f690>`.. I am beyond confused

Comment: Can you share the website URL it's failing on (at least one `page_data` value)? Also, provide a complete traceback.

Comment: @alexce I've just been looking and for the last few hours it appears the site I'm using to test this code on has been down for maintenance.  Earlier this morning not the case, so I'm going to wait until their back up and then retry to look for errors